# How to quickly move one layer to a different group in large Photoshop files, without dragging?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

Large website design with many, many layers. Need a way to move one element to the new designated group without dragging forever in the layers palette.

Comment: Not sure what you're working with, but it sounds like you should split your PSD so that you're not working with so many layers.

Comment: This doesnt answer your question but its worth mentioning that you can group layers with a keyboard shortcut. <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> (Windows) or <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> (Mac) will group layers together into a new group.

Comment: @Joonas updated my answer for you. Thanks for pointing out my carelesness :)

Answer (score 3):

To make any process easier close groups when you are not actively working with them. Then click and drag a layer while positioning your cursor towards the bottom of the layers panel (to get an automatic scroll).

I'm interested in reading other suggestions since this behaviour can be quite annoying.

Answer (score 3):

you could cheat by dragging the layer to a new document, scrolling up in the Layers palette, and then dragging it back into the original document.

Comment: You can also hit `Ctrl + Shift + ]` to move the layer to the top of the layer order.

Comment: @ckpepper02 Or Apple-Shift-] on Mac. Man, I *love* learning new shortcuts. :D

Answer (score 3):

Right click on a layer on your Artboard and you'll see a list of two things:

1. Layers that are directly under the Cursor
2. All groups

Now:

1. Click the layer you want to move.
2. Right click again and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while clicking the group you want to move that layer to. Both the layer and the group are now selected
3. Right click again and at the bottom choose `Isolate Layers`
4. Move the layer into the group as you want to
5. Turn off Isolate

Don't remember when Isolate Group was added so if you're using an older version of Photoshop this might not be available but it works in CreativeCloud

Here's the isolate switch:

[image]

Comment: Joined this SE just to upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of, but ff you try and keep an organised PSD from when you create it, using groups to do this, you can then use CMD click on the > to open / close all groups. Using this technique, you should be able to move layers around no problem at all.

[image]

[image]

You can also colour code layers (or a group to code all of the contents too), this can be extremely helpful in files with lots of layers. Right click the layer or group and select the colour you want.

[image]

[image]

Also don't forget, using smart objects can be pretty useful for keeping files tidy. Right click the layer and click Convert to Smart Object.

[image]